# Magento homepage not loading properly

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, magento-1.8

I have this website http://www.veneesa.com , my website load properly when open first time, but when i visit any other page (such as catgory or product page) and click back to homepage, 2 images comes (here is the screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zc0g6.jpg) and then website loads

can any one tell what is the problem?

Thanks for help

Comment: what browser are you using? it loads fine for me

Comment: Perhaps the carousel waits until it's ready before rendering, so the content underneath temporarily jumps up to fill the space.

Comment: @WombleGold yes that is the issue, do you have any idea how to solve this?